# angular loading submodule fails

Tags: angularjs, module

I'm new to AngularJS and I have a problem loading a submodule.
Heres is my index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="moduleEditing">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="moduleController as modCtrl" style="width: 960px; background-color: #CECECE;">
        <h1>{{modCtrl.projectName}}</h1>
        <video-module></video-module>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/video/js/video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app2.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app2.js :

```
(function(){
    var app;
    app = angular.module('moduleEditing',['moduleEditing-video']);

    app.controller('moduleController', ['$http', function($http){
        this.projectName = 'A page with editable modules';

    }]);

})();
```

And here is the video.js :

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('moduleEditing-video', []);
    app.directive('videoModule', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl : 'tpls/video-module.html',
            controller : ['$sce', function($sce){

                alert('qsdfsdqf');

                this.mode = 'edit';
                this.moduleName = "Vidéo module";
                this.videoTitle = "Première vidéo editable !";
                this.videoUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.youtube.com/embed/_23NTywgO6E');

                this.changeState = function(){
                    if (this.mode === 'edit') {
                        this.mode = 'save';
                    } else {
                        this.mode = 'edit';
                        // On met à jour la base de données
                    }
                }

                this.changeUrl = function(){
                    this.videoUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(this.videoUrl);
                }
            }],
            controllerAs: 'videoCtrl'
        };
    });
});
```

When I load the page, I'm getting this error : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=moduleEditing&p1=%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.5%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DmoduleEditing-video%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.3.5%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DmoduleEditing-video%250AA%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A6%253A416%250ALd%252F%253C%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A21%253A338%250Aa%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A20%253A483%250ALd%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A21%253A1%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A35%253A84%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A7%253A300%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A34%253A436%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A35%253A101%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A7%253A300%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A34%253A436%250ALb%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A38%253A154%250Arc%252Fd%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A17%253A339%250Arc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A18%253A155%250AGd%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A16%253A467%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A249%253A246%250Aa%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A164%253A12%250Agf%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fangular%252Fjs%252Fangular.js%253A32%253A288%250A%0AA%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.js:6:416%0Ag%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.js:35:358%0Ar@http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.js:7:300%0Ag@http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.js:34:436%0Ag%2F%3C@http:%2F

By I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. 
The submodule doesn't seem to have any code errors and all the files are loading well and in the right order.

Thanks for your ideas.

Pierre M.

Comment: Have you double checked that all paths to the javascript files are correct?

Comment: Yes. Alan show me what was missing. thanks for your ansmer.

Answer (score 1):

In video.js, you're not calling the function - you're missing the () from the end of the statement:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('moduleEditing-video', []);
    app.directive('videoModule', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl : 'tpls/video-module.html',
            controller : ['$sce', function($sce){

                alert('qsdfsdqf');

                this.mode = 'edit';
                this.moduleName = "Vidéo module";
                this.videoTitle = "Première vidéo editable !";
                this.videoUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.youtube.com/embed/_23NTywgO6E');

                this.changeState = function(){
                    if (this.mode === 'edit') {
                        this.mode = 'save';
                    } else {
                        this.mode = 'edit';
                        // On met à jour la base de données
                    }
                }

                this.changeUrl = function(){
                    this.videoUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(this.videoUrl);
                }
            }],
            controllerAs: 'videoCtrl'
        };
    });
})();
```

Comment: :/ :/ :/ So sorry for being such a blind ! Thanks :)

Comment: Those things are really hard to spot :)

Comment: Yes. Let's say that ;)